# Prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(Y,d)$ and that the sequence $(a_n)$ does not converge in $(Y,d)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(Y,d)$ be a sub-metric-space of a metric space $(X,d)$. Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $(Y,d)$ that converges in $(X,d)$ to a point $a \in X \setminus Y$; that is, $a$ lies in $X$ but not in the subspace $Y$. Then:

1. The sequence $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(Y,d)$.
2. The sequence $(a_n)$ does not converge in $(Y,d)$.

Lemma: If $(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$, then $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

Proof. Suppose $(a_n) \to l$, where $l \in X$. Let $\varepsilon >0$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that if $n,m >N$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $d(a_n,l)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $d(a_m,l)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

As $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then by the triangle inequality, $d(a_n,a_m) \le d(a_n,l)+d(l,a_m)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon \Rightarrow d(a_n,a_m)<\varepsilon$.

Because $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrarily chosen element of $(0,\infty)$, it follows that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

Proof. Suppose $(a_n) \to a$, where $a \in X \setminus Y$. As $(Y,d) \subseteq (X,d)$, then $(a_n) \in (Y,d) \Rightarrow (a_n) \in (X,d)$. Since $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then by the lemma, $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(Y,d)$.

Assume for contradiction that $(a_n)$ does converge in $(Y,d)$, so let $(a_n) \to b$, where $b \in Y$. Because $Y \subseteq X$, we have $b \in X$. This means that $(a_n)$ converges in $(X,d)$ whereby $\exists a,b \in X$ such that $(a_n) \to a$ and $(a_n) \to b$. But limits are unique in a metric space, which means that $a=b$. This contradicts the premise that $(a_n)$ is a  sequence in $(Y,d)$ that converges in $(Y,d)$. Therefore, $(a_n)$ does not converge in $(Y,d)$.

Is my reasoning here fine?

Comment: Looks okay to me. For extra clarity, you might want to add to the second last paragraph the following way "..., then by the lemma, (a_n) is a Cauchy sequence in (X,d), and thus it is also a Cauchy sequence in (Y,d) as they have the same metric."

Comment: Agreed with @Bio: More specifically, you have shown that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy in $(X, d)$, but you need to show that it is Cauchy in $(Y, d|_{Y \times Y})$.